# NavigationBar overrides other view controllers in tabBarController

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, navigationbar, tabbar

I have a swift tab bar controller with 4 view controllers. I am setting the navigationBar title with self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = "title" 
on each of the 4 view controllers. When I run the app the correct title appears when I click on each of the 4 tabs in order: "A," "B," "C," "D," but when I go to click on the other tabs after clicking tab D, the title only appears at "D." I feel like the title for tab D is overriding the other titles for some reason.

I've tried setting the title in different ways but still encounter the same problem.

Comment: Let me guess, you're setting the titles in viewDidLoad() of your view controllers, and only your tab bar controller is embedded in navigation controller, right?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I'm setting titles in viewDidLoad() and the view controllers are embedded in the tab bar controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a single **UINavigationController**, and your **UIViewControllers** (embedded in **UITabBarController**) ***viewDidLoad()*** are called one time once you click on the controller corresponding tab. You can either embed each of your **UIViewController** s in its own navigation controller and set its title in ***viewDidLoad()*** like *navigationItem.title = "title"* instead of changing the one of your UITabBarController, or change it in one of **UITabBarDelegate** or
 **UITabBarControllerDelegate** corresponding ***didSelect*** functions.

Comment: I embedded each in a navigation controller using  UINavigationController(rootViewController: AppHomeController()). Now I am trying to get the tab bar to disappear when navigating to other view controllers.

Comment: You can control it using tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden property.

Comment: I did this but when I go back to the tab bar controller there is a tab bar embedded in a tab bar. How do I avoid this?

Comment: Well, usually I set tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true in viewWillAppear and tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false in viewWillDisappear in the view controller presented from one of the tab bar view controllers to hide the tab and restore it state on navigating back.

Comment: I'm still encountering the same problem where the tab controllers are embedded.

Comment: There's you second tab bar comes from? Can you attach some pictures of your storyboard?

Comment: I'm not using storyboards, everything is programmatic.

Comment: Ok, so how do you present another view controller and go back?

Comment: I navigate to it on a button press #selector(searchClassesAction) and @objc func, back using dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil) in viewWillDisappear

Comment: Can you share your code for presenting the controller and the controller’s code as well?

Comment: tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false ended up working, thanks